# Number of multiplications in a pseudo code

Tags: loops, for-loop, time-complexity, pseudocode

Consider the following pseudo code. What is the total number of multiplications to be performed?

```
D = 2
for i = 1 to n do
   for j = i to n do
      for k = j + 1 to n do
           D = D * 3
```

Well I came across this question while learning to figure out complexity of algorithms.
How can one go about solving these types of questions its easy to say it has a upper bound of O(n^3) but how to find out exact number of multiplications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following calculations will give the exact number of multiplications in your code.

[image]

**EDIT:** As stated in the comments, the final result can indeed be simplified by two.

Comment: Wow that is some simplification. Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: And one more thing could I know the simplification used where (n-j) reduces to j and range changes from j=i->n to j=0->n-i?
And also how(n-i)(n-i+1) reduces to i^2+i

Comment: It's just a variable substitution to get back to the a basic sum of k elements. The only thing is I kept the same name j, which can be a little confusing, but it is the same as if I wrote `k = n-j`. It might not be crystal clear, but it's quite hard to explain it here in a comment... Is it?

Comment: You can simplify the final result by two.

Answer (score 0):

[image] . [sorry , I was unable to use latex here]